# Combining two lists taking all possible combinations into account

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a matrix and a list of the following

`m={{a1,a2,a3},{b1,b2,b3},{c1,c2,c3},...,{z1,z2,z3}}; l={4,5,6}`

I want to add `l`to `m` by taking all the possible combinations into account, so the combined matrix should look like

`updatedm={{a1,a2,a3,4},{a1,a2,a3,5},{a1,a2,a3,6},{b1,b2,b3,4},...,{z1,z2,z3,4},{z1,z2,z3,5},{z1,z2,z3,6}}`

How may I can do this job? I think `KroneckerProduct` should work in this case, but the outcome with the function is a little bit different.. it produces `{{a1,a2,a3,4,5,6},...,{z1,z2,z3,4,5,6}}`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m = {{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3}, {z1, z2, z3}}; 
l = {4, 5, 6};
```

You can also use [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html) + [`Append`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Append.html):

```
Join @@ Outer[Append, m, l, 1]
```

> ```
>  {{a1, a2, a3, 4}, {a1, a2, a3, 5}, {a1, a2, a3, 6}, 
>   {b1, b2, b3, 4}, {b1, b2, b3, 5}, {b1, b2, b3, 6},
>   {c1, c2, c3, 4}, {c1, c2, c3, 5}, {c1, c2, c3, 6},
>   {z1, z2, z3, 4}, {z1, z2, z3, 5}, {z1, z2, z3, 6}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
updatedm = Flatten /@ Tuples[{m, l}]
```

List-of-lists variant of `Tuples` does this directly, you just need to flatten (or `Apply@Append`) entries of `l` for each element of output to achieve your intended result.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much!